# Обход проверки на бота в Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Подскажите, как оптимизировать работу бесконечного цикла? После 30 прохождения пишет: `captcha verifed failed`. Он меня начинает воспринимать как робота, как "очеловечить" код? Что уже только не делал.Заранее благодарен

```
import time

import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium_stealth import stealth
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager



url = "site"

while True:
    ua = UserAgent()
    options = uc.ChromeOptions()

    options.add_argument(
        "user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36")
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
    options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
    options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
    options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
    options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)

    options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")
    options.add_argument("--profile-directory=Default")
    options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
    options.add_argument("--disable-plugins-discovery")
    options.add_argument("--incognito")
    options.add_argument("user_agent=DN")

    email = 'example@mail.com'
    phone_code = '374'
    number = '25564564665'

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options,
                              executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())  # Иногда нужно явно указать адрес
    # web драйвера executable_path=r"F:\GIT\siteparser\seleniumparse\chromedriver.exe"
    stealth(driver,
            languages=["en-US", "en"],
            vendor="Google Inc.",
            platform="Win32",
            webgl_vendor="Intel Inc.",
            renderer="Intel Iris OpenGL Engine",
            fix_hairline=True,
            )
    driver.delete_all_cookies()
    driver.maximize_window()

    while True:
        try:
            driver.get(url=url)
            city = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "centre"))))
            city.select_by_visible_text('Yerevan')
            time.sleep(2)

            driver.find_element(By.ID,
                                'app_type1').click()
            time.sleep(2)

            driver.find_element(By.ID,
                                'phone_code').clear()

            driver.find_element(By.ID,
                                'phone_code').send_keys(phone_code)
            time.sleep(2)
            driver.find_element(By.ID,
                                'phone').send_keys(number)
            time.sleep(2)
            driver.find_element(By.ID,
                                'email').send_keys(email)
            time.sleep(2)
            category = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "category"))))
            time.sleep(2)

            category.select_by_visible_text('Prime Time')
            time.sleep(2)

            driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,
                                'close').click()
            time.sleep(2)

            element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "save")))
            actions = ActionChains(driver)
            actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
            time.sleep(4)

            element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "agree")))
            actions = ActionChains(driver)
            actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
        except:
            continue
```

Comment: Вы пытаетесь обойти проверку на робота. Боюсь, что такое лежит за пределами этого ресурса

Comment: Спасибо за ответ,буду знать

Comment: `Что уже только не делал` - напишите что делали, иначе получите одни и те же советы. Например - менять IP адрес.

Comment: Я менял слипы и пробовал разные waitы,но не в этом дело,попробую с другим ip

Comment: Не подскажете пожалуйста как правильно реализовать с другим ip?